# Реализовать зум на интерактивной карте

Tags: javascript, html, css, карты

Здравствуйте! Необходимо реализовать зум на интерактивной карте. 
Выполнена интерактивная карта в виде div'a, значки на карте выводятся при помощи .tpl тегов {пример}. То как зум будет управляться - неважно, но желательно чтобы было удобно.

Код карты сейчас:

```
<div id="right_block_title2" style="margin-top: 0px;     width: 1060px;"> Интерактивная карта игрового мира</div>
<div id="main_block" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 28px;    width: 1060px;">
<div style="position:relative; width:1000px; height:1000px; background:url(/images/map/map.jpg);">
{gzones}
{buy}
{bbuy}
{base}
</div></div>
```

P.S. Пробовал реализовать при помощи различных js, например zoom image jquery, решение не подошло, т.к. приближалась только картинка карты, а значки {base} {gzones} и т.д. - не отображались.

Comment: Сделайте код воспроизводимым, посмотрите как добавить [mcve]

Comment: повесьте на клик, по соответствующей кнопке, изменение свойства `transform:scale()` у главного div'a  или div'ов. Еще вариант: увеличивать/уменьшать ширину и высоту)

Comment: "повесьте на клик" можно подробнее про это?)